# How to import a dashboard using NEST in C#?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to import a dashboard into Kibana via API from an exported dashboard called "export.ndjson"; however, I did not see an API for importing or exporting saved objects. How do you import saved objects into Kibana in C#, preferably using the NEST API?